# Arducam Refusing to Connect but other Camera works with OpenCV

Tags: camera, opencv, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye-64

I have a problem with my Arducam OV5647 M32076M20. It simply will not work unlike the other generic rpi camera I have on the same code. I am unsure if there are any other dependencies that I need for this.

Things to note:

- `vcgencmd get_camera` returns `supported=1 detected=1, libcamera interfaces=0`
- I am using `OpenCV` and `tkinter` and its basically just a simple program that shows what the camera sees when its turned on. It works on other camera except the one I've shown
- I have a script that detects camera with cv2 and it returns positive with `video0` usually

  ```
   for i in range(10):
       vid = cv2.VideoCapture(i)
       if vid.isOpened():
           status_label.config(text="Camera Found\tPort: video" + str(i), fg="green")
           print("Camera Found port: " + str(i))
           break
  ```
- GPU Memory is at `256`
- `libcamera-hello` runs and I see myself in the camera but I cannot get it to work in the software I coded
- Legacy Camera is `enabled` in `raspi-config`
- Details of `cat /etc/os-release`

  ```
   PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
   NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
   VERSION_ID="11"
   VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
   VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
   ID=raspbian
   ID_LIKE=debian
  ```

Really stumped at this. does Arducam have specific dependencies that I somehow missed. -I am just hoping that theres no need to buy the same module again to compare- **Edit: Nope. Even with another module its still the same**

Edit:
I tried `dmesg` and saw these

```
    [ 1638.317199] unicam fe801000.csi: Failed to start media pipeline: -22
    [ 1678.153954] unicam fe801000.csi: Wrong width or height 640x480 (remote pad set to 1296x972)
```

I am still trying to figure out what this means

I get `global cap_v4l.cpp: 1119 tryIoctl VIDEOI0(V4L2:/dev/video0): select() timeout` now that i did a fresh install and everything.